# Como exibir dados de uma linha específica de um banco de dados sem saber qual linha se trata?

Tags: php, mysqli

Olá.
Tenho um `while` que imprime na tela uma lista com todos os nomes das empresas do meu banco de dados:

```
$sql = "SELECT `nomep` FROM `cadastropn` WHERE `cidade` = '$cidade'";
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
        while($linha = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<div id="lista"><img src="_imagens/pizzaiolo_corpo-300x288.png" class="logo"><a href="javascript:mostrar();"><h2>'.$linha['nomep'].'</h2></a></div>';
```

Cada registro dessa lista, quando clicado, faz esse article ser mostrado:

```
<article class="detalhes">
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT `nomep`, `descricao`, `funciona`,`googlemaps`, `telefone`, `cidade`, `bairro`, `endereco`, `site`, `email`, `facebook`, `googleplus` FROM `cadastropn` WHERE `cidade` = '$cidade' && `id` = '1'";
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
        while($linha = $result->fetch_assoc()) { (...)
```

A minha dúvida, é que esta lista sempre mostra, o resultado de um mesmo item, mesmo quando eu clico em outros (o que é esperado por que eu indiquei o id acima) Agora como fazer o seguinte: Cliquei no primeiro item da lista e no article detalhes vai aparecer o registro de `id = '1'`. Então Cliquei no segundo item da lista e no article detalhes vai aparecer o registro de `id = '2'`, assim sucessivamente.

Comment: Aconselho a usar javascript e pegar o id do elemento que clicou, sendo que este id deve ser o mesmo que está no banco.

Comment: @NayronMorais  Pode exemplificar?

Answer (score 0):

No caso, você tem de passar a variável `$id`, em sua `query`,onde está, `id = 1`, passe a variável, `id = $id` .Por exemplo : `$cidade` em seu SELECT, é um valor variável, vindo de algum lugar, que não está em seu código, faça o mesmo com o campo "id".

***Pelo Javascript***

Substitua esse trecho:

```
 echo '<div id="lista"><img src="_imagens/pizzaiolo_corpo-300x288.png" class="logo"><a href="javascript:mostrar();"><h2>'.$linha['nomep'].'</h2></a></div>';
```

por

```
 echo '<div id="lista"><img src="_imagens/pizzaiolo_corpo-300x288.png" class="logo"><a id="linkq" href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" onclick="javascript:mostrar();"><h2>'.$linha['nomep'].'</h2><h2 id="id">'.$linha['id'].'</h2></a></div>';
```

Seu `function mostrar()` se deixa assim:

```
function mostrar(){
         var id = document.getElementById("id").innerHTML;
         var el = document.getElementsByClassName("detalhes");
         el[0].classList.toggle("show");

         var url = document.URL + "?id=" + id;
         var element = document.getElementById('linkq');
             element.setAttribute("href",url);
}
```

E por fim seu php

```
<article class="detalhes">
        <?php
        if(isset($_GET["id"])){
        $id = $_GET["id"];
        $sql = "SELECT `nomep`, `descricao`, `funciona`,`googlemaps`, `telefone`, `cidade`, `bairro`, `endereco`, `site`, `email`, `facebook`, `googleplus` FROM `cadastropn` WHERE `cidade` = '$cidade' && `id` = '$id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
            while($linha = $result->fetch_assoc()) { (...)}
        }
```

Removendo o item "feio" da div:

**no css se coloca**

```
#id{display:none;}
```

***Usando $_SESSIONS***

```
session_start();
$sql = "SELECT `nomep` FROM `cadastropn` WHERE `cidade` = '$cidade'";
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
        while($linha = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $_SESSION["id"] = $linha['id'];
            echo '<div id="lista"><img src="_imagens/pizzaiolo_corpo-300x288.png" class="logo"><a href="javascript:mostrar();"><h2>'.$linha['nomep'].'</h2></a></div>';
```

***E a outra parte***

```
<article class="detalhes">
        <?php
        $id = $_SESSION["id"];
        $sql = "SELECT `nomep`, `descricao`, `funciona`,`googlemaps`, `telefone`, `cidade`, `bairro`, `endereco`, `site`, `email`, `facebook`, `googleplus` FROM `cadastropn` WHERE `cidade` = '$cidade' && `id` = '$id'";
        session_destroy();
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
        while($linha = $result->fetch_assoc()) { (...)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<div id="lista"><img src="_imagens/pizzaiolo_corpo-300x288.png" class="logo"><a href="javascript:mostrar();"><h2>'.$linha['nomep'].'</h2></a></div>';
```

Coloca o identificador "lista" como classe, e coloca o id como sendo o id do banco, desta forma:

```
echo "<div class='lista' id=".$linha['id']."><img src="_imagens/pizzaiolo_corpo-300x288.png" class="logo"><a href='javascript:mostrar();'><h2>'.$linha['nomep'].'</h2></a></div>";
```

Agora só pega o id do elemento por javascript no momento do click e passa em sua consulta.

Ficaria assim de uma forma bem simples:

```
 echo "<div class='lista' id=".$linha['id']."onclick='mostrar(this.id);'">
```

Usa a função da outra resposta que dá certinho.
....

```
function mostrar(id){

         var url = document.URL + "?id=" + id;

}
```

E por fim seu php

```
<article class="detalhes">
        <?php
        $id = $_GET["id"];
        $sql = "SELECT `nomep`, `descricao`, `funciona`,`googlemaps`, `telefone`, `cidade`, `bairro`, `endereco`, `site`, `email`, `facebook`, `googleplus` FROM `cadastropn` WHERE `cidade` = '$cidade' && `id` = '$id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
        while($linha = $result->fetch_assoc()) { (...)
```

Comment: Sou bem novato em javascript. Como seria essa função do javascript?